# Sharepoint - how to get metadata for multiple files

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, dynamics-crm, sharepoint-api

Using below sharepoint Endpoint we can fetch the metadata for specific file.
GET https://domain.example.com/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(URL)/ListItemAllFields

Is there any way using which we can fetch metadata of all files from particular folder?

In above case we need to give multiple  call if we need to fetch metadata for more than one file. SO trying to find out if we can fetch metadata for multiple files in one call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `getFolderByServerRelativeUrl` endpoint to fetch the files and the associated metadata as below in a single call :

```
https://<your-site>/sites/test/_api/web/getFolderByServerRelativeUrl
('/sites/Test/Documents/FolderName/')/Files?$select=ListItemAllFields/*
&$expand=ListItemAllFields
```

Comment: Above command giving "ListItemAllFields@odata.navigationLinkUrl" for each file (not metadata itself). We need to call that url again to get exact metadata.

Comment: Sorry... I put it wrong... your endpoint working perfect :) its returning metadata for all files in one call... thanks a lot :)

Comment: is there any way to get “Modified By” filed of file also along with metadata?

Comment: This endpoint returns the `EditorId`. Using that, you can make a call to the `getusersbyid` endpoint as pass this value like [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/148331/8068)

Comment: With below filter it can be achieved: $select=Name,Length,ListItemAllFields,ModifiedBy&$expand=ModifiedBy,ListItemAllFields

Answer (score 0):

@Gautam Sheth -

Thanks for your reply. Above call is giving list of all files and link to get metadata for each file (instead of metadata itself). Here we again need to call individual endpoint to get exact metadata.

```
   "value": [
    {
        "odata.type": "SP.File",
        "odata.id": "file 1 path')",
        "odata.editLink": "file 1 pat')",
        "ListItemAllFields@odata.navigationLinkUrl": "file 1 path/ListItemAllFields"
    },
    {
         "odata.type": "SP.File",
        "odata.id": "file 2 path')",
        "odata.editLink": "file 2 path')",
        "ListItemAllFields@odata.navigationLinkUrl": "file 2 path/ListItemAllFields"
    }
```

Comment: Adding "&$expand=ListItemAllFields"  solved the problem